# How to get a dSYM file from appstoreconnect?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, dsym

Now Activity tab has been removed from iTunes connect. How to get the released iOS app dSYM file from iTunes connect?

Answer (score 0):

This is the process to get the dSYM file from Appstore connect.
Version Information ---> Click on the Build ---> Select Build Metadata ---> Click on Download dSYM